# Attach file on telegram with long message

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I need send to telegram long text with music/video/Doc.
How can send long text with video/music/doc using bot?
When upload file to server, telegram send me file_id and file Describe; how to attach this to my long text ?

Comment: I believe your question is answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40667602/5863267).

Answer (score 1):

You can't attach more than **200** chars to media caption, you can only link to other text, but it looks not pretty. :(

Try post it to your public channel with [t.me/Chan/ID](https://t.me/SeanChannel/29) link, or post to [Telegraph](https://telegra.ph/api).

BTW, you can suggest it to [@BotSupport](https://t.me/BotSupport), they may consider to change this limit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use telegram web-version.
In web-version there is no character limit and you don't need any bot. Many of these bots put image under the text.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays with Telegram bots you can send files with 0-1024 chars in caption [Documentation is here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument)

Though, If you have more than 1024 characters in your caption, you should get file's URL first. By your bot token and file_id  `https://api.telegram.org/file/bot<token>/<file_path>` Then when you send message with `sendMessage()` method you should set your text with and URL like that: `[...text => "<a href='your file's url'>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​</a>".$text,...]`